# Adding time constraints in PHP in the SQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently in my code, any student can leave any amount of feedback. I want to make it so each student can only give two feedbacks in one semester.

I think I also have to apply some kind of primary key concept in MySQL too?

Here is my code for reference:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_POST['r1']) && isset($_POST['r2']) && isset($_POST['r3']) && isset($_POST['r4']) && isset($_POST['suggestion']) && isset($_POST['module'])) {
        $module = $_POST['module'];
        $user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $r1 = $_POST['r1'];
        $r2 = $_POST['r2'];
        $r3 = $_POST['r3'];
        $r4 = $_POST['r4'];
        $suggestion = $_POST['suggestion'];
        switch ($module) {
        case 1:
            $query_insert = "INSERT INTO `wp_feedback` VALUES ('" . $user . "','wp','" . $r1 . "','" . $r2 . "','" . $r3 . "','" . $r4 . "','" . $suggestion . "')";
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                if ($query_run = mysql_query($query_insert)) {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sucessfull');</script>";
                    header('Location: feedback.php');
                }
                else {
                    echo "not inserted";
                }
            }

            break;

        case 2:
            $query_insert = "INSERT INTO `wp_feedback` VALUES ('" . $user . "','hssn2','" . $r1 . "','" . $r2 . "','" . $r3 . "','" . $r4 . "','" . $suggestion . "')";
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                if ($query_run = mysql_query($query_insert)) {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sucessfull');</script>";
                    header('Location: feedback.php');
                }
                else {
                    echo "not inserted";
                }
            }

            break;

        case 3:
            $query_insert = "INSERT INTO `wp_feedback` VALUES ('" . $user . "','dwds','" . $r1 . "','" . $r2 . "','" . $r3 . "','" . $r4 . "','" . $suggestion . "')";
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                if ($query_run = mysql_query($query_insert)) {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sucessfull');</script>";
                    header('Location: feedback.php');
                }
                else {
                    echo "not inserted";
                }
            }

        case 4:
        case 3:
            $query_insert = "INSERT INTO `wp_feedback` VALUES ('" . $user . "','ped','" . $r1 . "','" . $r2 . "','" . $r3 . "','" . $r4 . "','" . $suggestion . "')";
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                if ($query_run = mysql_query($query_insert)) {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sucessfull');</script>";
                    header('Location: feedback.php');
                }
                else {
                    echo "not inserted";
                }
            }

            break;

        default:
            echo "select something";
            break;
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You must be login to View the contents');</script>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Before insertion, use `COUNT(1)` and check?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
SELECT * FROM feedback WHERE studentid=123 AND feedback.insertdate BETWEEN startofthissemesetr AND endofthissemester

$reccount = number of records returned by the above query

if ($reccount > 1) {

    echo "sorry, you already submitted 2 feedbacks this semester!";

} else {

    echo "thank you for submitting your feedback!";
    insert feedback into DB

}
```